# How to prevent access based on MAC Address in local network and internet?

Tags: access-control

I have one server with source code of softwares. I want to give access based on certain MAC address to developers in my office. And also want to give access to some other employee who can also work from their home.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what type of base system you are using: is the server linux? unix? is source control svn? git? perforce?

Comment: Filtering by MAC is not what you want to do. Anyone can change their MAC and MAC is only useful on the local network segment.

Answer (score 2):

I can change my mac address, so I wouldn't depend on addresses. Addresses are like names, not like passwords.

I probably would use ssh keys, such as described at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-ssh-configuration-keypairs.html for Red Hat. There are other articles for other OSs.